# Is it possible to exclude bad memory?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook-pro, memory, error

I have a MacBook Air 2012 (A1466) and it developed some memory errors.
It crashes every half hour and Apple Hardware Test says

> 4MEM/9/40000000: 0x79eea590

Unfortunately, RAM is soldered on the motherboard and it is not replaceable.

I did some research and found that it is possible to tell the operating system to ignore wrong memory addresses if you use Linux: [Ubuntu Forums: Exclude Bad Memory](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1342957)

**Is is possible to somehow exclude faulty RAM addresses in Mac OS X?**

I currently use Yosemite (10.10) but, I am willing to downgrade if necessary.

Comment: I have about the same problem. I've 16GB RAM in my MacBook and it seems like not even 56k of it are defect. I definitly don't want to pay a lot of memory to replace everything. I just want that bad memory to be flagged for not using (or somehow blocked)

Answer (score 1):

Your only option is to replace the offending hardware.  Unfortunatley, if you were able to hack a solution together, it would be removed after subsequent updates.  With El Capitan and later, SIP would prevent you from doing this.

You have two options:

- Replace the logic board - very expensive  ($700 to $1000 USD)
- Replace the RAM modules - less expensive ($300 to $500 USD)

There are shops that will do this type of repair like [Rossman Group](https://www.rossmanngroup.com/) in NYC.  (Disclaimer:  I am not affiliated with this company in any way, I am just a satisfied client).  They can do board level repairs like this for half of what it would cost to replace the logic board.

That said, you may be able to find a functional (used) logic board on eBay as well.